# How to detect that Android device doesn't have built-in battery?

Tags: android, android-auto, batterymanager, android-automotive

Some of my users have head unit devices on Android (in their cars) and of course such device doesn't have battery and the next code returns `0`

`val batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)`

and the next method will return `false`

```
val status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1)
val statusCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
```

I have a video recording app and it stops recording automatically if `batteryLevel <= 1 && !statusCharging`

And it stops recording for such devices which don't have any battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT` which according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#EXTRA_PRESENT), exposes a:

> boolean indicating whether a battery is present.

Comment: so I will receive this extra on `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast?

Comment: Yes it should do. But make sure you test it and if it doesn't then let me know!